# How do I view PDFs in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

I have enabled Chrome PDF Viewer but the PDF files are still being downloaded. How do I stop this and view these PDF files within Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

```
<embed src="http://test.com/cool.pdf" width="500" height="750">
```

this will embed a pdf in your html. chrome and other browsers would show the pdf as a part of the page. Thus browsers won't download it.